# How do i edit 'date' in an edit form using bootstrap and jquery datepicker?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I cant seem to make the 'date' display in an  edit form and use datepicker at the same time. Heres the code.  I've tried using 'class' and 'id' to call the jquery. Datepicker and php edit form all work fine,,just not in the same value box.

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Date Agent Instructed</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group"  >
        <span class="input-group-addon"   style="cursor:pointer"  > <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"  ></i></span>
  <input type="text" style="cursor:pointer"  readonly="readonly" name="date_instructed" class="date2"   class="form-control"  value="<?php echo $row[14];?>"   >
```

Jquery

```
$(" .date2" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'}); $(".date2").val('');
```

Comment: What does your console say?  Any errors?

Comment: its like the datepicker overides the php as it returns nothing in the field when i add class="date2" to the code

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve?  It is hard to tell from the code provided.  Like why are you setting the value to nothing after you instantiate the date picker?

Comment: @SymeonQuimby You're right - `$(".date2").val('');` is going to remove the PHP echo'd value.

Comment: thanks manassehkatz  , i am that bad i needed you to actually say..'delete' $(".date2").val(''); from your code. thx

Comment: @Glen Symeon and I should split the points :-) Glad it was an easy fix.

Comment: nope take the points i didnt even realise it was an answer.... prob my fault

Comment: @Glen - Actually, Symeon posted a comment, I clarified/commented on that, then you worked from my comment while Symeon was turning it into an official Answer. All is good in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".date2").val('');
```

This piece of code is emptying your input field.  If you want to keep the original value you are echoing into the field via PHP, you will need to remove this piece of jquery code as it is setting the value to nothing.

Comment: Awesome thanks . i was trying to work out why the class was conflicting with the value, but it was the js causing the problem. many thanks.